# What is the indefinite integral of zero?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, indefinite-integrals

From the definition of indefinite integral I might say: Since the derivative of a constant is zero, thus the indefinite integral of zero is a constant. Therefore:
$$
\frac{dc}{dx} = 0 \quad\iff\quad
\int 0dx = c, \quad\forall c\in\mathbb{R}
$$

However... we know that $0\in\mathbb{R}$, and since zero is a constant, I can pull it out the integral:
$$
\int 0dx = 0\cdot\int 1dx = 0\cdot(x+c) = 0
$$

And then we end up that integral of zero is zero, not an arbitrary constant.
Where is wrong here?

Comment: This is great fun!

Comment: I think treating zero as a constant isn't right, since it's a determined value.

Comment: @alexjo The title is somehow coincidentally identical to this question, true. But, I'm actually asking a different thing.

Comment: @Physicist137 Did you read the most up-voted answer? It deals with your question.

Comment: @Physicist137 If you haven't read it, Sam DeHority answered your question as well though.

Comment: I read it. However, it only says I can't do that. It don't say why, or prove why, and this is what I want.

Comment: @Physicist137 uhmm, actually the answer in the link explains quite well what's going on here.

Comment: The thing is, that when we prove the rule $$\int k\cdot f(x)\ dx=k\cdot\int f(x)\ dx$$ this is done by applying the rule $(k\cdot F(x))'=k\cdot f(x)$ which is true even for $k=0$. But having equality of derivatives only ensures equality of primitive functions up to a constant, so in reality we have for $F(x)=\int k\cdot f(x)\ dx$ and $G(x)=k\cdot\int f(x)\ dx$ that $$F(x)=G(x)+c$$ so a constant on the outer level will make everything "add up".

Comment: @Physicist137: I tried to answer your specific version of the question in a comment. I hope it helps although your question was marked as duplicate.

Comment: @String Interesting answer. Good answer indeed. If you want to, I asked [another question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1069664/is-indefinite-integration-non-linear) about it. Perhaps you can answer over there.. :)

Comment: @Physicist137: You received a particularly nice answer there by vadim123. I am not going to try to compete with that ;)